# How do I avoid a content.css request for each TinyMCE instance?

Tags: css, optimization, iframe, tinymce

I think I'd like to have many TinyMCE instances on one page, but initializing a bunch of them seems pretty slow.  One thing that stands out is that each instance is doing a GET request for the content.css for its theme.  Making sure that CSS is cacheable is one approach, but can I avoid making some of those requests in the first place?

Or, since each TinyMCE instance is an iframe, does it need to do a request for each one?

Comment: Caching is key here.  If it is set up correctly, it will never make that request. A cache lookup will be negligeable performance-wise

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know the request is made and you cannot do much about it (except using caching). We already tried to optimize tinymce initialization - especially css too. You have several options for optimization (except caching):

- put all your css code used in your editor content into one single css file (the content.css of your selected theme)
- use gzip or another mechanism to have only one single request for all your css files on your page